# Dynamically Dimensioning A VBA Array?

Tags: arrays, vba

Why am I unable to set the size of an array based on a variable?  What's the best way around this?

```
Dim NumberOfZombies as integer
NumberOfZombies = 20000
Dim Zombies(NumberOfZombies) as New Zombie
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use a **dynamic array** when you don't know the number of values it will contain until run-time:

```
Dim Zombies() As Integer
ReDim Zombies(NumberOfZombies)
```

Or you could do everything with one statement if you're creating an array that's local to a procedure:

```
ReDim Zombies(NumberOfZombies) As Integer
```

**Fixed-size arrays** require the number of elements contained to be known at compile-time. This is why you can't use a variable to set the size of the array—by definition, the values of a variable are variable and only known at run-time.

You could use a constant if you knew the value of the variable was not going to change:

```
Const NumberOfZombies = 2000
```

but there's no way to cast between constants and variables. They have distinctly different meanings.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the ReDim statement to dynamically size arrays.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim NumberOfZombies As Integer
    NumberOfZombies = 20000
    Dim Zombies() As New Zombie
    ReDim Zombies(NumberOfZombies)

End Sub
```

This can seem strange when you already know the size of your array, but there you go!

Answer (score 2):

You can also look into using the Collection Object.  This usually works better than an array for custom objects, since it dynamically sizes and has methods for:

- Add
- Count
- Remove
- Item(index)

Plus its normally easier to loop through a collection too since you can use the for...each structure very easily with a collection.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a constant.

```
CONST NumberOfZombies = 20000
Dim Zombies(NumberOfZombies) As Zombies
```

or if you want to use a variable you have to do it this way:

```
Dim NumberOfZombies As Integer
NumberOfZombies = 20000

Dim Zombies() As Zombies

ReDim Zombies(NumberOfZombies)
```

Comment: Is there a tidier way to cast NumberOfZombies as a CONST right in the dimension definition? Dim Zombies(CONST NumberOfZombies) as new Zombie

Comment: I submitted my answer before I was finished typing.

Comment: Oh, I see, so a variable can be used to define a dimension if Redim is used, that is helpful to know, thanks!