# VBA: Creating an array of zeros with length equal to selection length

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Merry Christmas all. I'm new to VBA and excel for that matter. I only know how to program in python. I'm trying to create a fairly long macro but am encountering a lot of problems. First, I want to create an array of zeros, which has length equal to the length of the selected cells. I thought this would do it (where the array is called "Split"):

```
Sub mymacro()

    Dim Split(Selection.Rows.Count) As Integer

End Sub
```

But I get the "constant value expected" error. How can I do it? Cheers

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326678/dynamically-dimensioning-a-vba-array

Comment: What do you mean by the "array of zeros"?

Comment: By "an array of zeros" I mean an array in which every element is a zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [ReDim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251578%28v=office.15%29.aspx) statement later in your code.

```
Sub mymacro()
Dim Split() As Integer
... 
'in the code body
ReDim Split(Selection.Rows.Count) As Integer
End Sub
```

Two general suggestions:

1. Don't use "Split" as a variable name. It's a VBA function name.
2. Don't declare variables as `Integer`. Use `Long` instead. In this case, it's actually required, since `Integer` can't handle the number of rows in a sheet.